# What format is custom Helm chart repository?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am installing Kubernetes in a non-internet environment.  I want to use Helm and want to set up a custom chart repository.

`helm init` barfs after creating `~/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml` as it can't reach the default Google repo, so I will end up installing manually via kubectl - what is the format of this chart repository if I want to set up my own?

I will run `helm init --dry-run --debug` in order to get the manifest and amend this to point at a Docker registry that I have access to then install via `kubectl`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see the section in the docs here: https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_repository.md

It's a web server.

Answer (score 0):

A custom helm repository doesnt have to do anything with your kubernetes. Setting up the custom repo can be done without connecting even to any kubernetes cluster.

```html
helm init --client-only
```

Next step is to set up your custom repository somewhere like a storage account or whatever, then add that custom repo Url to your helm. So far this is all client side; you didnt touch your cluster yet.

```html
helm repo add <HELM-REPO-NAME> <HEM-REPO-URL>
```

The final step which is where you will need to connect to a real kubernetes cluster to install the helm chart using Tiller which lives inside your cluster.